# Bash Shell Issue

Tags: bash, shell, curl

```
currentDate="20160324"
headerDumpFile="header.txt"
#currentDate="$(date +’%Y%m%d’)"
printf "Current date in dd/mm/yyyy format %s\n" $currentDate

contId=""
labelList="c12,playlist-play,play,pause,end,playlist-end,heartbeat,ns_st_cl"

params="corporate=abc&user=abc&password=abc&startdate=$currentDate&site=abc&extralabels=$labelList"
url="https://example.com/v1/start?$params"

a=1

while true
do
curl -D $headerDumpFile -v -k -H "Accept-Encoding:gzip" $url > $a.zip 
contId= cat $headerDumpFile | grep "X-CS-Continuation-Id:" | awk '{print $NF}'

if [ "$contId" ];then
    printf "Breaking the Loop.."
    break;
fi
url="https://example.com/v1/start?$params&continuationId=${contId}"
a=$((a + 1))
echo $contId
echo $url
done
```

When i Do echo url its giving value of contId as blank but when i do echo $contId. Its printed correctly .Please suggest

Comment: Please post the real script code, especially the line that sets the `contId` variable which is broken.

Comment: It is getting set in While loop .....

Comment: It is not, look closer. The variable is temporarily cleared in a subsehll (pipeline component), certainly not what the real script wants to do.

Comment: When i do echo it is getting printed, it is not getting concatenated in last line....m new to shel scripting so any feedback is appreciated, before this code contId is just initialized...

Comment: Please fix the code posted in your question to match the code actually in your shell script. If it does really match, the value the `contId` variable might have when echo'ed is not set in the while loop but before.

Comment: You script is also missing a `done` instruction.

Comment: Its not semantic issue . Added done statement ..pasted just part of code ..ITs concatenation issue....url="https://example.com/v1/start?$params&continuationId=${contId}"; if I do echo $contId before and after url statement , its getting printed correctly...and I actually want to print the value set in while loop

Comment: how is this even running, there are multiple syntax errors.

Comment: pasted the whole code if it helps ;;

Comment: The whole code posted never sets the `contId` variable to anything but an empty string. It's no surprise it shows up as blank.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps is it what you want to achieve:

```
contId=$(cat $headerDumpFile | grep "X-CS-Continuation-Id:" | awk '{print $NF}')
```

Or the simpler:

```
contId=$(awk '/X-CS-Continuation-Id:/ {print $NF}' $headerDumpFile)
```

Note that unlike what you were guessing, `echo $contId` isn't displaying anything in your code. What is displayed is the result of the bogus `contId= cat $headerDumpFile | grep "X-CS-Continuation-Id:" | awk '{print $NF}'` line.

Comment: Then your logic might be flawed. You should tell what contains `header.txt`. It's hard to go further without knowing it.

Comment: I'm afraid not. Why would you want it?

Comment: And elaborate elaborate comments instead of something like "its not working" which is useless to figure out what tests you did and what results you got.

Comment: it worked . I used   contId=$(awk '/X-CS-Continuation-Id:/ {print $NF}' $headerDumpFile)...THanks :)...PLease let me know why it was not working with earlier statements

Comment: Both of my suggestions are equivalent so should produce the very same result. If the latter works for you, the former should have too. I already wrote a couple of times why your code wasn't working, you were clearing the variable and running a pipeline instead of affecting the variable with the result of the pipeline.